# Which Mongo instance in Replica Set is called and When will they be called?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I have a replica set which has three mongod instances (1 primary and 2 secondaries) and I set secondaries readable:

```
db.getMongo().setSlaveOk()
```

Therefore, in my understanding, all the instances are possible to be called. However, how may I know which instance is a application calling and when or in which situations will the secondaries be called for a application? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Writes in Mongo always get directed to the primary.

In terms of reads, it depends on the [Read Preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/).  Setting slaveOk tells the driver that the current connection should be allowed to read from a secondary, but the read preference still plays a role on what replica is queried.

Comment: Thank you. It means that it actually always calls primary to read. Secondaries are able to be read but actually no one calls. Then Here is my new question, how may i design a mongodb cluster to implement read balance while data traffic is quite large to maintain the query performance?

Comment: If you are ok with the potential for stale data, you could probably get away with using slaveOk and setting the readPreference to `nearest`